# My rails production server hangs on first request for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I am using Docker to host my Rails server and everything has been working perfectly fine with the exception of one thing: the first request to the web server after spinning up the container hangs for about 10-15 seconds. It's not a *huge* problem, but we re-deploy the rails container every time we push updates to production.

Initially, I thought it was because of assets precompiling, but I'm not quite sure that's the case.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.5-buster
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y awscli nodejs libxss1 libgbm1 libasound2 sendemail vim gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils tmux wget zip less
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile /myapp/
RUN bundle install
COPY . /myapp

# Add a script to be executed every time the container starts.
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

and here's my `entrypoint.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/sh
bundle install
rake db:migrate
rake db:seed
rake assets:precompile
npm install
set -e

exec "$@"
```

As shown above, it's running `rake assets:precompile` already, so any idea why the server hangs on the first request for a good 15-20 seconds? Is there anything else I can run upon or before starting the server so that all initial and subsequent requests are seamless and smooth?

Also using Rails 5.2.3

Comment: It doesn't look like you're actually starting the Rails server.  Do you need to set `CMD ["rails", "start"]` instead?

Comment: I think it would be best to precompile the assets during build time instead of when the docker container starts. Precompiling is usually a heavy process that will increase the time needed until your server is ready to accept connections.